# Replacement for SQL Server CE for ClickOnce applications

Tags: clickonce, embedded-database

I have come to the conclusion that SQL Server CE isn't a viable product. Between the versionsing issues and the impossibility of a non-administrator install it just doesn't work at my company.

Off hand I'm thinking about Jet, Oracle Berkeley, and SQLite. Given that I'm using .NET with ClickOnce, what embedded database would you recommend and why?

Comment: Hmm, according to this: http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx SQL CE has "Support for ClickOnce, XCopy, MSI, CAB, and non-admin embedded installation options" - so the issue is not replacing SQL CE rather changing what the setup wants to do...?

Comment: Even if I could get the installer issues fixed, the database version issue is still painful. There is no GetVersion, so I have to guess whether or not to upgrade the DB file.

Comment: @Murph At least with MSSQLCE4.0 you cannot use ClickOnce. From [MSDN  How to Deploy a SQL Server Compact Edition Database with an Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190958.aspx)  "***Important**
Because of the registry installation, SQL Server Compact can only be installed by a user with administrative credentials.*"

Comment: @IanBoyd that's certainly true for the installer - but my understanding was that you could do xcopy deployment of the .DLLs - I'll have to investigate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hands down, SQLite - so long as your data entities can fit within its capabilities. Check out the various providers available and see what works for you. [This one](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) has worked well for me.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is something you should consider. It has a .net data provide, is fast and probably provides everything you need.

http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried but you could use the DeveelDB, is written in C#: http://db.deveel.com/Main_Page